# Bots are registrating even when registration is disabled

Tags: joomla-2.5

I have discovered strange situation. Registration is disabled in administration users component. Despite it bots can register... When I go to /index.php?option=com_users&view=registration there's login form, not registration. Every day I have a lot of new accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd issue.

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of the Joomla 2.5 series (2.5.28)
2. If you're using any 3rd party extensions to manage users such as Community Builder, then make sure it's also up to date.
3. You may also want to test some 3rd party extensions to block bots registering such as [Stop Registration Bots](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/access-a-security/site-security/stop-registration-bots). Have a look at the [Site Security](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=138&filter%5Bincludes%5D=&filter%5Bversions%5D=&filter%5Btype%5D=&filter%5Bhasdemo%5D=&order=&filter%5Bnewupdated%5D=&filter%5Bscore%5D=&filter%5Bfavourites%5D=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1) category on the JED

#### Note, please consider migrating to Joomla 3.4 as 2.5 is no longer officially supported.

Comment: It's Joomla 2.5.16. Migrate to v3 is not possible. I'll check these extensions

Comment: 2.5.16? Serious? You're 12 versions behind! Please at least update to Joomla 2.5.28

Comment: Joomla uses Multisites extension and another sites on this same Joomla Instance had enabled registration and that was a problem.

Comment: Of course, done ;)